# Disable rectangle movement behavior in Report Designer

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

In SSRS, it is a good practice to put your report elements inside rectangles.
[image: Markup with Rectangles]

This makes it possible to move several items at once by moving the rectangle around. When moving the rectangle around with a mouse, this works like a charm: the Tablix position inside the Rectangle remains the same, so the Rectangle moves with all contents in-place to another position:

[image: Move rectangle by mouse]

However, when you manually (via the Top / Left properties in the properties pane) alter the position of these rectangles in Design Mode, the rectangle moves, *but the contents remain on the same place*.  So whenever I do the same movement via the properties pane (which is more precise IMHO), the contents are not moved along with the rectangle, and oftentimes even become invisible:

[image: Move rectangle via properties]

Whenever you alter the position of the Rectangle directly inside the XML of the report (in 'Code Mode'), the contents are moved along correctly - but this is a rather time-consuming way.

Is there a way to make SSRS move the contents of rectangles along in Design Mode, even when the position of the rectangles is altered via the properties pane?

Comment: ...and 7 years, 3 months later, this is still the behaviour in VS 2022. It's a maddening bug.